# Given a 4x4 Singular Matrix. find characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, characteristic-polynomial

I'm trying to solve this issue:

> Given A, a 4x4 singular Matrix. It is known that $\rho(A+2I)=2$ and $|A-2I| =0$.
>
> Find the characteristic polynomial of A, is A similar to a diagonal matrix?

I've found that because A is singular, 0 is an eigenvalue to A.

And because $|A-2I| = 0$, $|2I-A| = 0$ and 2 is also an eigenvalue.

I'm not sure what to do with the information of the rank. It would really help if I could find that $\rho(-2I-A) = 2$, but I don't know if that something I can claim.

Given that information, the geometric multiplicity of -2 is 2, and we have the eigen values of 0 and 2, which would mean the matrix is similar to a diagonal matrix. And the polynomial would be $p(x) = x(x-2)(x+2)^2$
Am I on the right path?
Thanks!

EDIT: Fixed "algebraic" to "geometric" in the last paragraph.

Comment: Your last paragraph is mostly correct. In fact, $-2$ has **geometric** multiplicity $2$, which is why we know that the matrix is diagonalizable.

Comment: Ah, Ben. Thank you once more for your help. :)
I meant it to be geometric, was a typo on my side. Fixing it, and thank you again.